# How does an air conditioner produce liquid

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, physical-chemistry, everyday-chemistry

I always notice that when an air condition is working and cooling the room it, is heating outside the room and a Liquid is dropping from the other side of the air conditioner. how does this happen and is it drinkable?, what is the name, is it water(H2O)?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because (a) the answer is easily found using an internet search engine; and (b) I'm not comfortable advising anyone on the consumption of water condensate from an air conditioning unit.

Comment: Hmmm... I've very comfortable advising not to drink the condensate. The condensate is not at all like distilled water.  Quite possibly lead solder on the coils plus heaven knows what sort of biological gunk (bacteria, mold, algae...) has grown from the air pulled through the coils.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not about chemistry.

Comment: Just because the condensate is contaminated post-condensation doesn't mean it is isn't being distilled.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At the risk of answering a question that may be better suited in Physics.SE, yes, it's water. It's condensation from the evaporation coil, which is where the refrigerant expands in order to cool the air drawn through the unit. That is how an AC unit also dehumidifies the air.

Chemically speaking, distilled water is drinkable, but it isn't great to drink. It can sap electrolytes from your body over time. From a unit like that, however, it may be contaminated with oils, rust, dirt, etc.